# Security Risks Associated with Sharing TrustStore

Tags: security, ssl, truststore

I have a situation where I would like to share my Production TrustStore JKS file with R&D for them to develop a script required for migration. What are the security problems here? How risky is that and how potentially it can be used?

I have tried to create a dummy TrustStore, but it differs from the production version, exhibiting some inconsistencies that I would like to avoid.

Comment: All you are sharing is a lot of public documents. As long as they are all CA certificates there is no information leak. If there are self-signed certificates in there, this is yet another reason not to use them.

Comment: Agree. Trust store is meant to hold the public root CA certificates which are by definition public. In the most common situation there is no risk involved.